# convert string or character to hex codes in javascript

Tags: javascript, codepages

I have a hex code table like this:

[image]

the code for "خ" is "A0" . now I want to write a function to get character or string and convert it to hex codes! how can I do that??

the language is Persian or Farsi .

Comment: Which encoding is this? Looks like [Iran System encoding](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_System_encoding), right? Seems to be very obsolete. Use Unicode instead (Wikipedia includes a (non-HTTPS) link to a conversion table to Unicode). `"خ".codePointAt() === 1582`, `"خ".codePointAt().toString(16) === "62e"`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon this table sheet is for a thermal printer and I have to use these codes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I searched and searched and tested, the only way was to convert charecter by character in a very long `if-else-if` statement !! It was also printed backward so I had to revert the string first. then numbers and english letters would be reversed so I had to made them reverse again!! It was a headache but worked!

Comment: This can be done with a lookup like in a hash map: `const asciiToIranSystem = String.fromCodePoint(...Array.from({ length: 0x80 }, (_, index) => index)) + "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹،ـ؟ﺁﺋﺀﺍﺎﺏﺑﭖﭘﺕﺗﺙﺛﺝﺟﭺﭼﺡﺣﺥﺧﺩﺫﺭﺯﮊﺱﺳﺵﺷﺹﺻﺽﺿﻁ░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀ﻅﻉﻊﻌﻋﻍﻎﻐﻏﻑﻓﻕﻗﮎﮐﮒﮔﻝﻻﻟﻡﻣﻥﻧﻭﻩﻬﻫﯽﯼﯾ\xA0"; const getHexCodes = ([...str]) => str.map((char) => asciiToIranSystem.indexOf(char));`, then `getHexCodes("xyz▓۱۲۳ﯼ");`. No `if` statements; yields an array of numbers (map it with `.toString(16)` to get hex formatting). Your answer doesn’t explain how to do it, so it’s not very useful.